# SSRS Grand Total should sum subtotals and not source values

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to sum timesheet entries by user, users enter actual duration and the report then applies a minimum 0.5 day rule to each user.

The problem is that the grand total is recalculating based on the source values when it need to sum the user subtotal after the 0.5 day rule is applied.

A day is defined as 7.5 hours

Formula used for rounding Ceiling(((Sum(Fields!minutes.Value)/60)/7.5) / 0.5) *0.5, this is used for the line items, subtotal and grand total.

This uses a Matrix control to display the data

Example

**Source Data**
user----minutes
Bob-----60
Bob-----60
Alice---1680

**Report**
user----days
Bob-----0.5
Alice---4
Total---***4***

What I actually want

**Report**
user----days
Bob-----0.5
Alice---4
Total---***4.5***

Comment: What expression are you using to sum up the total?

Comment: @Steve-o169 - Ceiling(((Sum(Fields!minutes.Value)/60)/7.5) / 0.5) *0.5

Comment: If you are using SQL to access your data, push the "days" calculation back up to the database and have the SQL statement return your days.  Then it's a easy to handle.  Personally, I tend towards this kind of solution becuase it give you greater control over the data.  In your case, you can have multiple fields returning the minutes, actual days (if needed) and calculated days.  With these in place, you should have full control of the data.

Comment: @FrankBall that would be my usual solution, but this is using a FetchXML data source

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment, it looks like you are summing up the total of using the field which would be the data from your dataset.  You'll need to modify the expression used to grab the data from the report item.  I don't know that I have total understanding of the report and how it works, but if each line item is using that same expression, you should be able to use the following expression to calculate the grand total.

```
= SUM(ReportItems!LineItemDays.Value)
```

Basically, you just need to sum the values given for each line item so sub in the name of the textbox that contains each line's day count and it should correct your issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Credit for this goes to @steve-o169 and @FrankBall for reminding me you can do aggregation in FetchXML**

As suggested above, I changed the FetchXML query to perform the aggregation at the server level, then added a calculated field on the data set to apply the formula and used the calculated field in the Matrix control.